# How to add end function to tictactoe discord BOT (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, tic-tac-toe

My tictactoe BOT can end the game only after a player wins. I need to add a function to the BOT such that it ends the game when a command is run.
How do I add the end function to this BOT?
For example : A game is in progress, I want to end the game in between. When I run a command, in this case -end, I need the BOT to stop the game.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import urllib.request
import re
import youtube_dl
import os
import requests

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= "-")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("READY TO PLAY TICTACTOE!!")
player1 = ""
player2 = ""
turn = ""
gameOver = True

board = []

winningConditions = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
]

@client.command()
async def tictactoe(ctx, p1: discord.Member, p2: discord.Member):
    global count
    global player1
    global player2
    global turn
    global gameOver
    if gameOver:
        global board
        board = [":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                 ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                 ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:"]
        turn = ""
        gameOver = False
        count = 0

        player1 = p1
        player2 = p2

        # print the board
        line = ""
        for x in range(len(board)):
            if x == 2 or x == 5 or x == 8:
                line += " " + board[x]
                await ctx.send(line)
                line = ""
            else:
                line += " " + board[x]

        # determine who goes first
        num = random.randint(1, 2)
        if num == 1:
            turn = player1
            myEmbed = discord.Embed(title= "GAME IN PROGRESS",description="IT IS <@" + str(player1.id) + ">'s TURN.",color=0xe74c3c)
            await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)
        elif num == 2:
            turn = player2
            myEmbed = discord.Embed(title= "GAME IN PROGRESS",description="IT IS <@" + str(player2.id) + ">'s TURN.",color=0xe74c3c)
            await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)
    else:
        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title= "GAME IN PROGRESS",description="A GAME IS STILL IN PROGRESS. FINISH IT BEFORE STARTING A NEW ONE",color=0xe74c3c)
        await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)

@client.command()
async def place(ctx, pos: int):
    global turn
    global player1
    global player2
    global board
    global count
    global gameOver
    if not gameOver:
        mark = ""
        if turn == ctx.author:
            if turn == player1:
                mark = ":regional_indicator_x:"
            elif turn == player2:
                mark = ":o2:"
            if 0 < pos < 10 and board[pos - 1] == ":white_large_square:" :
                board[pos - 1] = mark
                count += 1

                # print the board
                line = ""
                for x in range(len(board)):
                    if x == 2 or x == 5 or x == 8:
                        line += " " + board[x]
                        await ctx.send(line)
                        line = ""
                    else:
                        line += " " + board[x]

                checkWinner(winningConditions, mark)
                print(count)
                if gameOver == True:
                    myEmbed = discord.Embed(title= "WINNER!",description=mark + " :crown: ",color=0xf1c40f)
                    await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)
                elif count >= 9:
                    gameOver = True
                    myEmbed = discord.Embed(title= "TIE",description="IT'S A TIE :handshake:",color=0xf1c40f)
                    await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)

                # switch turns
                if turn == player1:
                    turn = player2
                elif turn == player2:
                    turn = player1
            else:
                myEmbed = discord.Embed(title= "PLACE ERROR!",description="BE SURE TO CHOOSE AN INTEGER BETWEEN 1 AND 9 (INCLUSIVE) AND AN UNMARKED TILE. ",color=0xe74c3c)
                await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)
        else:
            myEmbed = discord.Embed(title= "TURN ERROR!",description="IT'S NOT YOUR TURN",color=0xe74c3c)
            await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)
    else:
        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title= "START GAME",description="TO START A NEW GAME, USE -tictactoe COMMAND",color=0x2ecc71)
        await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)


def checkWinner(winningConditions, mark):
    global gameOver
    for condition in winningConditions:
        if board[condition[0]] == mark and board[condition[1]] == mark and board[condition[2]] == mark:
            gameOver = True

@tictactoe.error
async def tictactoe_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title= "MENTION ERROR!",description="PLEASE MENTION 2 USERS",color=0xe74c3c)
        await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title= "ERROR!",description="PLEASE MAKE SURE TO MENTION/PING PLAYERS (ie. <@688534433879556134>)",color=0xe74c3c)
        await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)

@place.error
async def place_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title= "NO POSITION",description="PLEASE ENTER A POSITION TO MARK",color=0xe74c3c)
        await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title= "INTEGER ERROR!",description="PLEASE MAKE SURE IT'S AN INTEGER",color=0xe74c3c)
        await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)
client.run("")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to not use *global* variables, as they are pretty dangerous and should only be used as read-only, you could simply pass these variables as parameters in your function.

Either way, if you want to reset your game, judging at your current code the easiest way to do it would be having a function that puts these *global* variables back to their original value, something like this:

```py
    @client.command()
    async def end(ctx):
        # We need to declare them as global first
        global count
        global player1
        global player2
        global turn
        global gameOver
        
        # Assign their initial value
        count = 0
        player1 = ""
        player2 = ""
        turn = ""
        gameOver = True

        # Now print your message or whatever you want
        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title= "RESET GAME",description="TO START A NEW GAME, USE -tictactoe COMMAND",color=0x2ecc71)
        await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution for this

```
@client.command()
async def tictactoe(ctx, p1: discord.Member, p2: discord.Member):
  
    global count
    global player1
    global player2  
    global turn
    global gameOver
    global p1_id
    global p2_id

    if gameOver:
        global board
        board = [":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                 ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                 ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:"]
        turn = ""
        gameOver = False
        count = 0
        
        p1_id = p1.id
        p2_id = p2.id
        player1 = p1
        player2 = p2
```

You first have to get player 1st and 2nd's id and then add them to global
And after that use a simple if else statement in end function

End Function:

```
@client.command()
async def end(ctx):
  global count
  global player1
  global player2
  global turn
  global gameOver
  global p1_id
  global p2_id

  if ctx.message.author.id == p1_id or ctx.message.author.id == p2_id:

    count = 0
    player1 = ""
    player2 = ""
    turn = ""
    gameOver = True

    myEmbed = discord.Embed(title= "Game Reset",description="To start a new game, USE $tictactoe command",color=0x2ecc71)
    await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)
  
  else:
    await ctx.send('Only those who started the game can end this game')
```

In @Shunya 's code , anyone can end the game , but In my code only those two person who started the game can end the game

I hope it'll help :)